# Ruby Mixin Undefined Method

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

So, I know there is a simple error, but I just can't seem to spot it. I'm using Modules/Mixins for the first time and any help would be much appreciated. I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `this_is' for Value:Module (NoMethodError)
```

But it looks like the method is there...Here are is my module and classes...

```
module Value
  def this_is
    puts "#{self.players_hand} is the players hand"
  end
end

require './value.rb'

class Player
  include Value
  attr_accessor :players_hand

  def initialize
    @players_hand = 0
  end

  def value_is
    Value.this_is
  end
end

require './player.rb'

class Game

  def initialize
    @player = Player.new
  end

  def start
    puts @player.players_hand
    puts @player.value_is
  end
end

game = Game.new
game.start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `include Value` inside of the `Player` class, you are making the `Value` module's methods a part of the `Player` class, so the `this_is` method is not namespaced. Knowing that, we need to change this method:

```
def value_is
  Value.this_is
end
```

To:

```
def value_is
  this_is
end
```